# Google Data Studio connector - "your app isn't verified", but OAuth connector is?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Google Data Studio community connector. When first authorizing the connector, users get this warning page:

[image: connector1.png]

So I went ahead and made a verified credentials OAuth connector thingy:

[image]

Users still get that warning page - naturally.
**BUT**! before submitting the verification request, on [this page](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/pscc-requirements), it says:

> Authorize and test your connector using a new account after passing
>   the OAuth verification process to ensure that Unverified app screen is
>   not displayed to your users.

Well, my OAuth credentials project *is* verified, any idea why I'm still getting the "app isn't verified" error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure OAuth verification was done for all the scopes that you require in your connector.

1. Check your connector scripts scopes by going to File > Project Properties > Scope in Apps Script UI.
2. In GCP Console, in the screen in your screenshot, edit the App to see the list of "Scopes for Google APIs".

Everything in #1 needs to be included in #2.

Comment: No luck. These are the scopes the connector is using: https://i.postimg.cc/0N5MZWRn/connector2.png

These are the ones included in the approved consent screen: https://i.postimg.cc/y8y3mq5W/connector3.png

Do I need to actually be using OAuth in the connector? I only want to remove the "app isn't verified" error.

Comment: 1. This OAuth verification is for the first party authentication, i.e. when a user authorizes your connectors. This has nothing to do with the third party authentication. Whatever you return in getAuthType is irrelevant for the OAuth verification. 2. Can you please confirm that your connector script is attached to the GCP project that was verified?

Comment: Whoops. I thought I was doing that by implementing a OAuth service that used the credentials' client_id and secret. Thanks a million, MK!